# Push data as sub Arrays in one array

Tags: php, arrays

I know that this is asked few times here but there is an advanced problem.

I got an array `$data` and I need to got this structure when `foreach`

```
$data[0] => [
    'value1' => string(x) "some data",
    'value2' => string(x) "some other data"
];

$data[1] => ... ...
```

I know that can't execute `array_push` with array keys also tried code bellow but I got two big arrays. I just need one big array with small sub arrays

**My Code**

```
    $authors['email'] = array();
    $authors['name'] = array();
    foreach (json_decode($response)->response->docs AS $docs)
    {
        $articleAuthors = explode(', ', $docs->authors);
        $i=0;
        foreach ($docs->email as $email) {
          array_push($authors['email'], $email);
            array_push($authors['name'], $articleAuthors[$i]);
            ++$i;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not sure to have understood well but instead of your two array_push, try `$authors[$i] = array('email' => $email, 'name' => $articleAuthors[$i]);` (and don't forget to initalize the empty array before the loop)

Comment: Why can you not have a direct map from 'author@example.com' -> Object containing various metadata like `name` etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, to get one array with little subarrays

```
$authors = array();
#...
foreach($docs->email as $email){
   array_push($authors, array('email'=>$email,'name'=>$articleAuthors[$i]));
   ++$i;
}
#...
```

Comment: Thanks you a lot, yes this do the job. This is solution for even bigger data to put in sub arrays. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I just find solution, code above is makeing two big arrays and just added line bellow.

```
$authors['email'] = array();
$authors['name'] = array();
foreach (json_decode($response)->response->docs AS $docs)
{
    $articleAuthors = explode(', ', $docs->authors);
    $i=0;
    foreach ($docs->email as $email) {
      array_push($authors['email'], $email);
        array_push($authors['name'], $articleAuthors[$i]);
        ++$i;
    }
}
```

$data = array_combine($authors['name'], $authors['email']);

Comment: You better construct directly the big array directly instead of pushing into 2 different arrays and then combining them in term of speed :)